# Bulk Insert Arguments SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

What arguments can be used to "filter" out CSV Bulk Insertions into my SQL Server Database. I have addresses that have commas in their name `Park Avenue, New York`, I also assume that hyphens and colon's are breaking bulk inserting as well.

I currently have

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[address]
FROM 'C:\Desktop\Datafiles\Address.csv'
WITH   
      (  
         FIELDTERMINATOR =',',  
         ROWTERMINATOR ='\n',
         FIRSTROW = 2   
      );
```

I can't seem to find anything that can help me.

Comment: What wasn't covered in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) that you want to understand?

Comment: If you have values that have commas in them, such as `Park Avenue, New York` you **must** quote identify the strings, and then use SQL Server 2017+, which supports quoted identifiers with the `BULK INSERT` command. Otherwise you *must* chose a delimited that does not appear in your values (the latter is just basic and good CSV definitions). This is why you find pipe (`|`) delimited is quite common. You can't have a CSV that uses a comma (`,`) as it's delimiter but also have data which contains commas in it where you don't quote identify it. That's just poor CSV design. Change the CSV's design.